# Building docker image with gitlab ci shared runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having some trouble getting Gitlab CI set up to build a docker image and push it to the Gitlab registry.  I am attempting to use a shared runner provided by Gitlab. From what I've read, this should be possible, however, no matter what I try, as soon as the build reaches any 'docker' command it fails, with this message:

```
  $ docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
/bin/bash: line 54: docker: command not found
```

I am using the following  CI configuration:

```
image: "ruby:2.3"

services:
  - docker:dind
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: test-db
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/pha3l/gitlab-ci-test-project:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/pha3l/gitlab-ci-test-project:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy


before_script:
  - ruby -v                               
  - gem install bundler  --no-ri --no-rdoc  
  - bundle install -j $(nproc) --path vendor

rubocop:
  script:
  - rubocop

rails:
  variables:
    DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB"
  script:
  - bundle exec rake db:migrate
  - bundle exec rake db:seed
  - bundle exec rake test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

release-image:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo 'Do the deploy!'
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like these lines

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

Do not add docker binary to your image, only allow you to running docker in docker. You may have to create your own image based on ruby:2.3 and add docker utility explicitly. Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.3
MAINTAINER maintaner

# install docker
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg2

RUN apt-key adv \
    --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
    --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

RUN echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-engine
```

Comment: Thank you. I came to the realization that I don't need a ruby environment in the first level, but only in the container that it creates.  I solved the problem by using the docker:git image as a base and writing a Dockerfile for the container it creates.